# How to detect errors using FluentPDO

Tags: php, database, pdo, error-handling

I am using [FluentPDO](http://lichtner.github.io/fluentpdo/) to build my queries.

When I execute an insert statement, it returns `False` if it is unable to do so. However, I am unable to figure out how to retrieve the error behind the failure.

Does anyone know how to handle errors while using this library?

This is my current code...

```
function doInsert() {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=blog", "root", "password");
    $fpdo = new FluentPDO($pdo);

    $values = [
        'field1' => 'value 1',
        'field2' => 'value 2',
        'field3' => 'value 3',
    ];

    $query = $fpdo->insertInto('my_table', $values)->execute();
    if (!$query) {
        // what to type here to determine error
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried emailing the author instead?

Comment: The bottom of the [manual page](http://lichtner.github.io/fluentpdo/) has a few tips on debugging. Have you tried them?

Comment: Emailed author, but he has himself posted on Github that he is too busy to work on the project. The debugging feature only gives details on generated query, parameters, row count, etc. and is not for error handling. Who ever is down voting just to get free stackoverflow points, better have a good justification. The question can always be edited based on feedback, but simple down voting is just lazy on your part.

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT the answer, but the explanation from author (FluentPDO/BaseQuery.php Line: 98):

```
    // At this point, $result is a PDOStatement instance, or false.
    // PDO::prepare() does not reliably return errors. Some database drivers
    // do not support prepared statements, and PHP emulates them.  Postgres
    // does support prepared statements, but PHP does not call Postgres's
    // prepare function until we call PDOStatement::execute() (below).
    // If PDO::prepare() worked properly, this is where we would check
    // for prepare errors, such as invalid SQL.
```